# How to Write a Function that Create and AppendChild HTML Elements in PHP?

Tags: php, html, function, appendchild, createelement

Instead of echoing large blocks of HTML code or using the `echo <<<HEREDOC`, I want to write functions that create HTML elements and append child elements to each other.

The `createLoginBar` function would create a div that I would attach to other HTML elements into my `createLogoutBanner` function.

```php
function createLoginBar() {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $login_bar = $dom->createElement('div');
    $login_bar->setAttribute("id", "login_bar");
    $dom->appendChild($login_bar);
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}

function createLogoutBanner() {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $login_bar = createLoginBar();
    $login_flex = createBlankLoginFlex();
    $banner_login_form = createBannerLoginForm();
    $login_message_flex = createLoginMessageFlex();
    $nonmember_signup_flex = createNonSignupFlex();
    $not_a_member_form = createNotAMemberForm();

    $dom->appendChild($login_bar); //This line gives an error
    $login_bar->appendChild($login_flex);
    $login_flex->appendChild($banner_login_form);
    $login_bar->appendChild($login_message_flex);
    $login_bar->appendChild($nonmember_signup_flex);
    $nonmember_signup_flex->appendChild($not_a_member_form);
    return $dom->saveHTML();
}
```

The `$dom->appendChild($login_bar);` line in the `createLogoutBanner` function is giving me Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: DOMNode::appendChild(): Argument #1 ($node) must be of type DOMNode, string given in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states `DOMNode::appendChild()` expects to be passed a `DOMNode`.
Your `createLoginBar` function is returning a string instead of the node.
Try the following change:

```php
function createLoginBar() {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $login_bar = $dom->createElement('div');
    $login_bar->setAttribute("id", "login_bar");
    $dom->appendChild($login_bar);
    return $dom; //->saveHTML();
}
```

You will then see the error `Fatal error: Uncaught DOMException: Wrong Document Error`. This is because you must use the same parent instance of `DOMDocument` to create the child nodes. Instead of creating a `new DOMDocument` inside each function, create a top level `DOMDocument` and pass it to each of the functions to use.

```php
function createLoginBar(DOMDocument $dom):DOMNode 
{
    $login_bar = $dom->createElement('div');
    // the following line will cause invalid html if this function is called more than once
    $login_bar->setAttribute("id", "login_bar");

    return $login_bar;
}
function createBtn(DOMDocument $dom, string $value):DOMNode 
{
    $btn = $dom->createElement('button', $value);
    $btn->setAttribute("class", "widget");

    return $btn;
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$login_bar = createLoginBar($dom);
$login_btn = createBtn($dom, 'login');

$login_bar->appendChild($login_btn);

$dom->appendChild($login_bar);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Result:

```
<div id="login_bar"><button class="widget">login</button></div>
```

[Sandbox](https://onlinephp.io?s=dZHPToNAEIfvJLzDhpBAE_oCVmusNfHQ6sW7WdgRNtnOkmWgB-O7u3-qIEWOzO-b-Wb29r5t2jj66LEiqZFVBjjBQdcSd9zk-9fjXlf9CZBYKvRpdWP_vGgBLI4-44jZL1Uu_F5yw-58Zr0NTZ4UOC7PhByy1WaeXm87oAciI8ueIE-kSAqW_JYTRwTGAPUGJ6itfF057wivdAvW2f5Ys3Tgqocl-5LwP2_rRRqz4ofejMhcvlK865z_WYoaaEHeQkE7jtwwOxPhzCbCuWP-HHP2Fv7-k4wXH3cP-2a-mIX502PztgUUj41UIh87XHJ--6UENyEBVaMvR-r4AM9vx4P1_QY%2C&v=8.2.1)

Comment: I made the changes but I'm receiving a new error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught DOMException: Wrong Document Error in... DOMNode->appendChild(Object(DOMDocument))...

Comment: Wow, it really worked. Thank you for taking your time and helping me out. You just pushed my learning so much further. I can't thank you enough. I have to edit a few things to match my previous styling but this was magnificent. Thanks again.